# Why the template BLANK ? Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know why my template is not being rendered anymore. I get a blank page. It worked before then after some tweaks it stopped working. I've reversed most of the code and i still don't get why is not working . There is no kind of error in the console. How am I supposed to debug this kind of behavior ?

Here is the controller

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var crmControllers = angular.module('crmControllers', []);

crmControllers.controller('TimelineCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
 function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

  var emailsId 
    emailsId = $routeParams.emailsId;

    $http.get('http://local.sf.com:8080/timeline/API?emailsId=' + emailsId, 
    {withCredentials: true}).success(function(timelines){

  angular.forEach(timelines, function(timeline) {

    var inboxIfr
    inboxIfr = 'http://local.sf.com:8080/messages/inbox?email='+
    timeline.Email+'&toEmail='+timeline.ToEmail+'&subject='+timeline.Subject
    timeline.inboxIfr = inboxIfr
    $scope.inboxIfr = inboxIfr
console.log(inboxIfr);

       });  
     });
}]);
```

inboxIfr shows up in the console log which means that the loop is happening but it's just not rendered.

Html

```
<body>
<ul ng-repeat="timeline in timelines">

<p>hello <p/>
 <iframe class="container well well-small span6"
           style="height: 400px;"
           ng-src="{{timeline.inboxIfr}}"></iframe>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var crmApp = angular.module('crmApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'crmControllers',

]);

crmApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/timeline/:emailsId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/time.html',
        controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/timeline:emailsId'
      });
  }]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="crmApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SF</title>
  <!--<<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">-->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">-->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<!--<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>-->
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>


  <html>

</head>


<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit : I've added some dummy text above `ng-repeat="timeline in timelines">` and it's being rendered so the real issue is that nothing is rendered  inside the ng-repeat loop .

Edit: I've reduced time.html to this and it's still not being rendered . Only the first paragraph is being rendered ("I can see this")

```
    <p>I can see this</p>
<li ng-repeat="timeline in timelines">


<p>I can't see this <p/>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default route isn't pointing to a valid route:

app.js:

```
.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/timeline:emailsId'
      });
```

shoud be:

```
.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/timeline/:emailsId'
      });
```

EDIT: More HTML/Angular mistakes:

- Remove body tags in Angular templates.
- Don't use `ng-repeat` with `<ul>` tags. Rather use it with `<li>` or other block-elements like `<div>`
- You use `ng-repeat` with the scope variable `timelines`, but you never set `$scope.timelines`

Comment: I don't think I see any difference ? both are same?! I also doubt is the routing issue given that I can see inboxIfr in   console.log

Comment: There's an additional `/` in the second one... also, in the template, you shouldn't have any `<body>` tags in it?

Comment: Thank you so much @Khoi. That was the issue ``$scope.timelines = timelines;`` . I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help!